# C# - Giving out user input not working

Tags: c#

So I've got this code. It takes the user input, but it does not display it as I want:

```
    double v = 0.1;
    string age;
    string name;
    string status;

    Console.WriteLine(v);

    Console.WriteLine("Hei buddy! What is your name?");
    name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Nice to meet you {0}. My name is PAI!", name);
    Console.WriteLine("How old are you {0}?", name);

    age = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Wow. So you are {1}-years-old. That's a huge number, as I am only x day old.", age);
```

where is the problem?

Comment: what is the problem? that's not how you declare variables.

Comment: You typed `{1}` instead of `{0}` in last `Console.WriteLine`

Comment: First of all, you cannot store `float` values in `int` , your all `string` declarations are wrong it should be `string <varName>;`.

Comment: @Aominè Yeah it was a typo. It was not the problem (as expected).
apocalypse: not the problem.

Comment: @YashKaranke same here. typo. not the problem.

Comment: @sn0wb4ll then correct your typos and include the error message you're getting.

Comment: My problem is that I get to the first input, but it does not come to the output "Nice to meet you [...]"

Comment: @sn0wb4ll I am not even sure how you're getting to the first input, the compiler should throw an error as you're storing a `float` value in `int` datatype. are you sure this is your own code? Please go through suggestions made by Aomine, apocalypse and me.

Comment: @YashKaranke I am getting to all inputs, cause there is nothing wrong with them.
The variables are correct, the point is that The console is only asking the two questions, without giving an output with the answer.

Comment: @sn0wb4ll Visual Studio IDE will throw an error on `int v = 0.1` as it's not an integer and its float.

Comment: As already mentioned before: `{1}-years-old.` -> `{0}-years-old.` (in the last `Console.WriteLine`)

Comment: @YashKaranke you mean double. as I said, all typos were fixed.
I just need to know how I convert the int so I can input and output it

Comment: You don't seem to understand what that argument means - and if you run in debug mode: this is *exactly* where you will get a runtime error

Comment: This question has been edited out so many times that it will affect to the explanation of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is a fix I came up with from what I understand your problem.

```
        int v = 0;
        string age;
        string name;
        string status;

        Console.WriteLine(v);

        Console.WriteLine("Hei buddy! What is your name?");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Nice to meet you {0}. My name is PAI!", name);
        Console.WriteLine("How old are you {0}?", name);

        age = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Wow. So you are {0}-years-old. That's a huge number, as I am only x day old.", age);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

I do not know why you've assigned a `float` value in `int`, so that's where your first problem was. Secondly, you were storing the value in `status` string and trying to print unused variable `name`. The third error was in placeholder {1} where you're taking input age and printing in placeholder `{1}` instead of `{0}`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fixed. I am new to input/output so I was confused.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double v = 0.1;
    string name;
    /*string status;*/

    Console.WriteLine(v);

    Console.WriteLine("Hei buddy! What is your name?");
    name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Nice to meet you {0}. My name is PAI!", name);
    Console.WriteLine("How old are you {0}?", name);

    int age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Wow. So you are {0}-years-old. That's a huge number, as I am only x day old.", age);
```

The only thing I need to know now is, how I can stop the console from closing automatically.

Comment: add `Console.ReadKey();` at the last line of your code.

Comment: @YashKaranke Thanks.